# How do I import variables, functions, etc. from inside a directory that's on the same level as the file I'm trying to import into?

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have something similar to the following file structure in a django project (example below is simplified).

```
/project

    /directory_1
          /file_1.py
          /file_2.py
    /file_3.py
```

Inside file_1.py and file_2.py are variables, dictionaries, and functions that I want to access inside of file_3.py.

file_3.py and directory_1 are on the same level.  I want to import the contents of file_1.py and file_2.py that are inside directory_1, which is on the same level as file_3.py, for use inside file_3.py.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)